# Developing a Mac Utility to Alter Screen Display/Output

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos, accessibility

I want to build a Mac OSX utility that alters the appearance of the screen on a level similar to OSX's native "White on Black", "Grayscale" and other contrast settings located in the Unversal Access area of the System Preferences. To be specific, I want to adjust the display to give off a darker appearance of the screen, so that it's not so bright at night because even the lowest brightness of the MacBook is still way to bright when being used at night. I haven't seen any Mac utilities offering such a capability so I'd like to create my own if possible (unless by chance you have come across something similar). I have experience creating Mac apps, but nothing of this caliber.

So I'm wondering, how would I go about creating such a utility? I know there are apps that require "Enable access for assistive devices" to be checked in the Universal Access preferences so they can alter windows of apps and so forth. I assume such a utility would also require this setting to be enabled in order to access some kind of low-level accessibility API, but I can't find any relevant information on the topic. I tried to hunt around on Apple's OSX developer documentation to see what could be done with such settings, but I didn't find anything useful. Is such a feat even possible to pull off? If so, how? If not, why? The solution would only need to support Snow Leopard, if that helps. :)

Comment: There is Flux: http://stereopsis.com/flux/. It doesn't do quite what you're hoping to do, but it might be worth investigating before you roll your own. It makes the color of your computer's display adapt to the time of day, warm at night and like sunlight during the day.

Comment: Interesting concept, and it's also cross-platform, though not apparently open source. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shady by Matt Gemmell does exactly what you describe (open-source):
http://mattgemmell.com/2009/11/02/shady-for-tired-eyes
It's basically a transparent window on top of everything.

You can also darken the screen by altering the color profile.

Comment: Interesting utility. I also read about several other similar utilities in the comments. My Google-fu must be seriously off, because I couldn't find any of these apps on Google! Anyway, thanks so much for the info. Sounds like I'll be saving a lot of work not having to mess with it, but also good for future reference, or for anyone else looking to alter the screen display/output. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the download link moved to Matt's business site: http://instinctivecode.com/shady/

Comment: Someone else had mentioned [Brightness Control](http://www.splasm.com/brightnesscontrol/index.html) which works on 10.2+ (for anyone not yet running Leopard). If nothing else, the description is a good read, and relevant considering I needed the functionality to allow myself to work on my MacBook in bed while my wife is sleeping. Good times :)